# How to change the active toolbar button highlight color in Eclipse (on darkest theme)?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, appearance

I use eclipse's darkest dark theme and like the colors it offers.

But I don't know why, on the toolbars, the active buttons, like the perspective I'm in, or the "Show console when standard error changes" button, don't seem to have any kind of difference beetwen active (pressed) and inactive.
Like Here :
[All the perspectives and not one seems active. I'm on the Java perspective.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM4AV.png)

Is there a way to change this or is this just a bug in my eclipse ?

Comment: Please be aware that this theme plugin tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Consider using a more ergonomic theme that doesn't have such issues if you don't like the themes built-in.

Comment: Do you have any recommandation of dark themes, aside from the eclipse default "Dark" theme that don't upse this loadtime weaving (the devStyle plugin I suppose) ?

Comment: As far as I know, that company is the only one doing such error-prone loadtime weaving. For ergonomic reasons I prefer a light theme. You might try the [Eclipse Spectrum Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-spectrum-dark-theme) which does not make such a technical nonsense and whose developers do not fight Eclipse, but support it. Please make sure that what bothers you most about the built-in dark theme has been reported to Eclipse (there are currently people working to improve it).

Comment: Thank you, this one is much better than the default dark. The built-in dark is not quite dark, there are places that are still kind of light.

Comment: Did switching away from the DevStyle theme resolve the issue with active/inactive buttons not having any difference? I'm experiencing the same issue since Eclipse 2022-09, but I'm just using the built-in Eclipse Dark theme.

Comment: Yes, it did. But I still got back to devStyle though because most of my appearance settings were done while using devStyle so, it was kind of with another theme and my own settings. I got used to not seeing the active perspectives and others.